# Compare variables in json and variables in MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, json, mysql-connector

I have JSON. I extract some fields and write them to a MySQL database.

I do it like this

```
public class Billing
{
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string address_1 { get; set; }
        public string address_2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
}

public class Shipping
{
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string address_1 { get; set; }
        public string address_2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int parent_id { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string order_key { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public bool prices_include_tax { get; set; }
        public string date_created { get; set; }
        public string date_modified { get; set; }
        public int customer_id { get; set; }
        public double discount_total { get; set; }
        public double discount_tax { get; set; }
        public double shipping_total { get; set; }
        public double shipping_tax { get; set; }
        public double cart_tax { get; set; }
        public double total { get; set; }
        public double total_tax { get; set; }
        public Billing billing { get; set; }
        public Shipping shipping { get; set; }
        public string payment_method { get; set; }
        public string payment_method_title { get; set; }
        public string transaction_id { get; set; }
        public string customer_ip_address { get; set; }
        public string customer_user_agent { get; set; }
        public string created_via { get; set; }
        public string customer_note { get; set; }
        public string date_completed { get; set; }
        public string date_paid { get; set; }
        public string cart_hash { get; set; }
        public List<object> line_items { get; set; }
        public List<object> tax_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> shipping_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> fee_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> coupon_lines { get; set; }
}

public async void Down()
{
    RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");
    WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);

    // Get all products
    var orders = await wc.GetOrders(new Dictionary<string, string>() {{ "per_page", "100" }});

    string products = orders.ToFormattedJsonString();

    List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(products);

    foreach (RootObject  root in rootObjectData)
    {
        int id = root.id;
        int customer_id = root.customer_id;

        string fio = root.billing.first_name +" " +"  "+ root.billing.last_name;
        string adress = root.billing.address_1 + " " + "  " + root.billing.address_2;
        double total = root.total;

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Database= milanoold_db;Data Source=144.76.133.122;User Id=milanoold_u;Password=sK5PvCDP; SslMode=None; CharSet=utf8"))
        {
            // Открытие соединения
            connection.Open();

            MySqlCommand addCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO orders (id,customer_id,total,fio,adress) VALUES ('"+id+ "', '" + customer_id + "', '" + total + "', '" + fio + "','" + adress + "' )", connection);
            addCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        //Debug.WriteLine(customer);
    }
}
```

But I have a problem: when I download JSON I need to compare which variables are in database and what are missing and write missing.

How I can realize this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: This app is for limited circle of people.

I need answer for my question. I know about parametrized queries.@marc_s

Comment: If you talk about something like this `string sql = @"SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE mob LIKE N'%' + @telephone + '%'";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", "+3333333333");`

Comment: is `id` or `customer_id` a unique identifier?

Comment: Yes,there are unique identifiers@Plutonix

Comment: anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: Just write an update if exists or insert if not.

Comment: you mean sql commands? @AVKNaidu

Comment: yes. check if your unique id exists and if it exists then update or insert

Comment: I can do it in foreach?@AVKNaidu

Comment: yes. but it will be slow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123466/discussion-between-eugene-and-avk-naidu).